# Configure error: libevent not found on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macos, configure, bitcoin, libevent

I am trying to compile bitcoin library and it throws this error

```
checking for mismatched boost c++11 scoped enums... mismatched
checking for SSL... yes
checking for CRYPTO... yes
checking for EVENT... no
configure: error: libevent not found.
```

i did install libevent through

```
brew install libevent
```

I see that the libevent core files are in /usr/local/lib but it is just not working.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I try to install pkg-config with brew and then it can find libevent when configuring.

There is a link for the similar issue - https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/11996